# How to get distinct values in Excel using formulas and tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What I am trying to accomplish is like using a SELECT DISTINCT in SQL.

I already know of formula arrays and the ribbon buttons, but that is still not enough.

The constraints I am working with are:

I have 2 Excel tables

One has duplicate values in one column.

I have to get only the distinct values in the second column.

Can you folks help me on that?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Two tables, but one table has duplicates in column 1, but you need **unique** values from column 2? What does column 1 or the other table have to do with?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility to get distinct value from a table or column, is to use a simple pivot table. Take the column with duplicate value as ROWS in the pivot and you will get a list without duplicate.